# android Position AlertDialog not working in 4.1 as on 2.3

Tags: android, position, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog, whose Y is set and set to show on center. It shows perfectly on 2.3 emulator & device, but on 4.1 (emulator & 4.0 device) it shows on more top than expected.
Here's the code :

```
        AlertDialog adg = scrnDlg.create();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(adg.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    //lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.y = 05;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    adg.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                adg.show();
    /*  working with 2.3 but nt proper position with 4.0
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = adg.getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.y = 05;
        lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        adg.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        */
```

Screen shot of obth versions emulator :
[image]

Can any one help me wort out this problem ?
Also this height is perfect for Ld, Md. But for Hd & xD this height seems to be small & more space is left on bottom. How do I set the height based on screen height.

Any help ishighly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the above by setting the Gravity by testing the Android OS Version. This is how I did and get resutls as expected :

```
alertDlg.show(); 
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(alertDlg.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.y = 02;
if (MyActivity.Build_Version < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL; 
else if (MyActivity.Build_Version >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

alertDlg.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Gravity of LayoutParams are treated differently by 4.1 and below 4.1 versions of the Android, thus the above is set and works perfectly.

Hope this sharing help someone.